# Unable to access or parse decoded json structure in PHP

Tags: php, shopify, json

I'm trying to access the decoded json structure, where `$encoded` contains the response from the shopify API GET `/admin/orders/450789469.json`  (Please refer to [their docs](http://docs.shopify.com/api/order#show)).

```
$decoded= json_decode($encoded_input, true);
var_dump($decoded);
```

The dump of $decoded displays the decoded nested arrays, but when I try to access the individual elements, nothing shows up.

```
echo $decoded->orders[0]->buyer_accepts_marketing;
```

Could anyone please explain why this the decoded json structure isn't accessible? Thanks

Comment: Also, the key is `order`, not `orders`.  According to their docs.

Comment: @RocketHazmat but the example response shows otherwise.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari: What example response?  Here is the API he is calling: http://docs.shopify.com/api/order#show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
$decoded= json_decode($encoded_input, true);
```

tells PHP to decode the string as an array, but then, at the line

```
$decoded->orders[0]->buyer_accepts_marketing;
```

you try to access it as an object. You could try using

```
$decoded['orders'][0]['buyer_accepts_marketing'];
```

instead.

EDIT: see also the docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

EDIT 2: according to the api specifications, you should instead access

```
$decoded['order']['buyer_accepts_marketing'];
```

Comment: I know it sounds weird, but just unable to retrieve the elements. This is the var_dump($decoded) showing the nested array structure:    array(3) { [0]=> array(48) { ["buyer_accepts_marketing"]=> bool(true) ["cancel_reason"]=> NULL ["cancelled_at"]=> NULL ["cart_token"]=> string(32) "be0dc3ae66a4791435394405372fff53

Comment: Please specify **what** have you dumped and **how** you tried to access it.

Comment: I've dumped imported orders as $decoded= json_decode($encoded_input, true);
var_dump($decoded);   I'm trying to display the elements of this structure as: $decoded['orders']['buyer_accepts_marketing'];

Comment: I can retrieve the elements in a loop as in **foreach ($decoded['orders'] as $order)
{
    echo "status:". $order['buyer_accepts_marketing'] ."\n";
   
};** But is there a way I can retrieve a single array element in just one statement?

Comment: Have you tried `$order = $decoded['orders'][0]` and then `echo $order['buyer_accepts_marketing']` ?

Answer (score 5):

When you use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) with "true" as the second argument, everything turns into arrays instead of objects.

Try `$decoded['orders'][0]['buyer_accepts_marketing']`